How can I report an answer?
I've asked my first question on Stack Overflow and someone answered my question within just a few minutes. However, the answer is most definitely AI generated. I know this is against the community rules.
Is there a way I can report this answer? Those AI generated answers really have no meaning.

How strange. Your Stack Overflow profile says you haven't posted yet...

"What if I see someone doing something bad?"

@pm-2ring That's weird, this is my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78905228/webpack-html-loader-doesnt-work-along-css-loader/78905236#78905236

You seem to have created two accounts by accident: the one you're posting from now, and the one you used to post that SO question. I suggest contacting staff and asking for them to be merged.

The general guidance on how to flag for moderator review is here: Flagging a post for moderator review.

For specific support about the SO, use the MSO site, which is Stack Overflow's Meta Site.

You can report it by clicking the flag button, selecting “In need of moderator intervention” and stating that you think it’s AI generated and if useful, why. However you haven’t posted anything else with this account so…I think you might have accidentally made 2 accounts.
